# CakePHP 2 Forms and 2 Different Models

Tags: forms, cakephp, view, controller, models

I have a feature in my project called calendar. Users are able to add 'Events' and 'Event Types'

When a user clicks on 'Add New Event', he or she is redirected to the 'Add New Event' page. Inside the page contains a dropdown field 'Event Type'. There's also a button 'Add New Event Type' on the same page. Clicking the 'Add New Event Type' button will open up a modal which contains the form for the Event Type.

So my view contains 2 forms. 1 for Events and 1 for Event Types. I also have 2 controllers and 2 models, each belongs to Events and Event Types.

My problem is that when I try to create a new Event Type, I get an error about Event.

But when I create a new Event, everything goes smoothly.

I also made sure that I didn't use nested forms.

This is my form structure:

```
$this->Form->create('Event');
//other input fields
$this->Form-end($add);

*inside a modal*
$this->Form->create('EventType');
//other input fields
$this->Form->end($add);
```

Comment: What error you get about event ?

Comment: In ```$this->Form->create('EventType');``` you must set path to controller and action where you save data. By default your post request going to events controller and add action.

Comment: you should use different value for  `$add`.

Comment: @Salines: That solution totally worked! Thank you!